# Is there a way to skip certain tests by default in Codeception?

Tags: unit-testing, codeception

I'm adding unit tests to a project that did not originally have tests. A lot of the code makes real changes to file systems, databases, web calls, etc. so I'd still like to be able to test it, but safely until such time as I can refactor it to allows mocks in testing.

I know how to explicitly skip tests in Codeception with `--skip` or `--skip-group`, but is there a way to skip "dangerous" tests by default, unless they are specifically included? Ideally, I'd like to define a group called `dangerous` (or something similar), and add the tests that should only be run with caution to it.

Looking through the source code for Codeception, there doesn't seem to be a configuration option for it.